# How to pass some function using my own library in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I make a library that call the method to show some lastest news in the footer.

my library :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Footer
{
    protected $ci;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
        $this->ci->load->model('m_main');
    }

    public function news_footer()
    {
        return $data['news_footer'] = $this->m_main->last_news_footer()->result();
    }

}
```

my controller :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('m_main');
        $this->load->helper('text');
        $this->load->library('footer');
    }

    public function index(){
        $data['whychooseus']    = $this->m_main->data_whychooseus()->result();
        $data['iklan']          = $this->m_main->last_iklan()->result();
        $data['iklan2']         = $this->m_main->last2_iklan()->result();
        $data['bannerx']        = $this->m_main->data_banner()->result();
        $data['news']           = $this->m_main->data_news()->result();
        $data['newslast']       = $this->m_main->last_news()->result();
        $data['provinsi']       = $this->m_main->data_provinsi()->result();
        $data['kota']           = $this->m_main->data_kota()->result();
        $data['bengkel']        = $this->m_main->data_bengkel_kota()->result();
        $data['harga']          = $this->m_main->data_harga()->result();
        $data['plat']           = $this->m_main->data_plat()->result();
        $data['news_footer']    = $this->m_main->last_news_footer()->result();

        $this->footer->news_footer();
        $this->load->view('index',$data);
    }
```

and i got this error :

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined method CI_Loader::last_news_footer()
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\premi\application\libraries\footer.php
>
> Line Number: 16

Can someone help me?

Comment: How did you go did you try my answer.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 my boss wont using that huh, so i load the m_main model in all controller haha

Answer (score 3):

Try using `ci`

```
$this->ci->m_main->last_news_footer()
```

---

If your trying to load controllers with in controllers you can use HMVC it good for widgets etc

https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/downloads/?tab=branches

Note there is a bug on latest version of HMVC add this https://pastebin.com/vNUhJCss